# How to calculate NSDate between two NSDate in IOS

Tags: ios, date, between

I want show whether particular office is opened or closed depends on the weekday

i am getting office timings from my server

```
        NSString *open = @"10:00 AM";
        NSString *close = @"6:00 PM";
         NSDateFormatter *df11 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [df11 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
         NSString *date11=[df11 stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
       NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
         NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
        NSString *dte1 = [df stringFromDate:date1];
        date1 = [df dateFromString:dte1];
        NSString *dte2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",date11, open];
        NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:dte2];
        NSString *dte3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",date11,close];
        NSDate *date3 = [df dateFromString:dte3];

      if([date1 compare:date2]==NSOrderedDescending && [date1 compare:date3]==NSOrderedAscending)
          open=YES;
         else 
              open=NO;
```

In this case i didn't get any problem, but for some other office i got like this

```
        NSString *open = @"11:30 AM";
        NSString *close = @"12:30 AM";/*means here day is changing but still i am using current date
```

for this case the above code is not working, bcoz of day changes, i am not getting any idea how to follow, i was struggling from last day for solution

please help me 
 thank you

Comment: First: Indent the code!  Second: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: see my edit now u might understand my problem

Comment: That's much better indeed, but why all those empty lines, and why place `{`'s inconsistently?  Don't you see it's looks messy, still?  Clean code helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

get days between two dates

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2013-08-08"];
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2013-09-09"];

NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];

int numberOfDays = secondsBetween / 86400;

NSLog(@"There are %d days in between the two dates.", numberOfDays);
```

You can also get different between two dates [GO](https://github.com/jonhocking/PrettyTimestamp)

Comment: Here you have to put condition when February Month or not.

Comment: What's with February?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the week day and hour from the date and do an explicit test on them:

```
const NSInteger openHour = 10;
const NSInteger closeHour = 18;

NSDate *dateToTest = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit
                                           fromDate:dateToTest];
BOOL open =
    [components weekDay] >= [calendar firstWeekDay] &&
    [components weekDay] < [calendar firstWeekDay] + 5 && 
    [components hour] >= openHour &&
    [components hour] < closeHour;
```

Comment: could u plz expalin a liitle bit more, bcoz i am not getting in this format

Comment: means i am getting miniutes also from service